# How to transform HTML code block in Gatsby with syntax highlighting using Prism.js?

Tags: gatsby, prismjs

I want to apply syntax highlighting to HTML content that has `<code>` tag; e.g.

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    function hello () {
      console.log("Hello!");
    }
  </code>
</pre>
```

Gatsby plugins such as [gatsby-remark-prismjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-prismjs/?=code), only work on **Markdown** files. I am trying to generate the pages programmatically using `gatsby-node.js`.

Comment: You can could place your snippet into a file and using `gatsby-source-filesystem` add additional fields to certain files using the `onCreateNode` hook. This might not make sense for smaller snippets. for example https://gist.github.com/sktt/a9fc3706aca3516157bfc07ea3b078a3 which you could then fetch with graphql

Comment: alternatively, use a webpack loader to transform the raw code into formatted html,

Comment: I also want to do this. I've found this so far: https://github.com/octalmage/jason.stallin.gs/blob/master/src/components/BlogContent.js#L16-L32

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
import Prism from 'prismjs'

const Component = () => {
 let code_example = `let myvar = 'hello'`
 let html_example = Prism.highlight(code_example, Prism.languages.javascript, 'javascript{numberLines: true}')

 //...

 return (
  <pre class="language-js">
   <code class="language-js" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html_example }}></code>
  </pre>
 )
}
```

But I haven't been able to use *line numbers* here